# C language. How to manage the struct returned by a function?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, return-value

I am a beginner in C and programming overall, so sorry for the possible trivial mistakes. Let me briefly explain my case.

I have the struct students:

```
typedef struct {
    int id;
    char name[20]
    int grade;
} students;
```

and I have the variable `students student[20]` that contains names, ids and grades of each student

and also have a pointer function of type students (I hope I am calling it properly, correct me if wrong) which has to return the pointer to the student with the highest grades:

```
students* topStudent(students student[20]) {
    ...
    //let's say I have found the student with the top grades and his index is 4.

    return &student[4];
}
```

Now, let's say I want to manage this student[4], but, **How do I do that?**
For instance, I want to have `student[4]`'s fields (id, etc.) copied in another variable `students topstudent` so that I directly worked with it further.

I tried this:

```
students *topstudent;
topstudent = topStudent(student);
```

but whenever I try to work with `topstudent`, for example like this:

```
printf("%i %s %i", topstudent.id, topstudent.name, topstudent.grade);
```

or when I tried to put `&` before the `topstudent.id`, `topstudent.name` and `topstudent.grade`, it gives 3 errors for each of the fields (`request for member 'name' in something not a structure or union`). (I guess there's something wrong with the declaration and using of `topstudent`, or I am not applying correct methods for pointers, or something else I am missing).

So, could you please tell me the correct way of doing that? Feel free to get to know the details, if needed. Thank you, I do appreciate your help!

Comment: Do you know the difference between a thing and a pointer to a thing?

Comment: `Team`? What is that?

Comment: `int i = 5; int *p = &i; printf("%d\n", p);` <- why doesn't it print 5?

Comment: sorry, it was supposed to be students

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`topstudent` is a pointer, so you have to dereference that to access the structure.

You can use unary `*` operator to dereference a pointer.

```
printf("%i %s %i", (*topstudent).id, (*topstudent).name, (*topstudent).grade);
```

Alternatively, you can use `->` operator. `A->B` means `(*A).B`.

```
printf("%i %s %i", topstudent->id, topstudent->name, topstudent->grade);
```

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation! I see the mistake, fixed it, it works perfectly. Looks like I didn't get pointers, going to restudy them thoroughly.